# conflict error in yum CentOS

Tags: centos, repository, yum

Some times im using yum and get an error about confliction between repositories so i googled for this problem and i found some temporary solution like `--enablerepo` 
here my error

```
Error: Package: php-5.4.44-50.el6.art.x86_64 (atomic)
       Requires: php-cli(x86-64) = 5.4.44-50.el6.art
       Installed: php-cli-5.6.12-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi-php56)
           php-cli(x86-64) = 5.6.12-1.el6.remi
       Available: php-cli-5.3.3-40.el6_6.x86_64 (base)
           php-cli(x86-64) = 5.3.3-40.el6_6
       Available: php-cli-5.3.3-46.el6_6.x86_64 (updates)
           php-cli(x86-64) = 5.3.3-46.el6_6
       Available: php-cli-5.4.42-48.el6.art.x86_64 (atomic)
           php-cli(x86-64) = 5.4.42-48.el6.art
       Available: php-cli-5.4.43-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           php-cli(x86-64) = 5.4.43-1.el6.remi
       Available: php-cli-5.4.43-49.el6.art.x86_64 (atomic)
           php-cli(x86-64) = 5.4.43-49.el6.art
       Available: php-cli-5.4.44-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           php-cli(x86-64) = 5.4.44-1.el6.remi
       Available: php-cli-5.4.44-50.el6.art.x86_64 (atomic)
           php-cli(x86-64) = 5.4.44-50.el6.art
       Available: php-cli-5.3.29-4.w5.x86_64 (webtatic)
           Not found


You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

So can you guys help me ?

Comment: little more details please, the command you executed. What are you trying to install precisely?

Comment: I'm trying to configure load-balancer  on my vps and i ran this command :
 `sudo yum groupinstall --enablerepo=remi "load balancer"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your description, PHP 5.6 is installed from remi-php56 repository, so the simplest solution is to enable this repository permanently, setting enabled=1 in the repository configuration file, and thus all PHP packages will be pulled from there, and should not create any conflict.

Adding "--enablerepo=remi-php56" on each yum command also works.

Notices:

- you also have "atomic" and "webtatic" enabled. Having various repositories providing the same stuff (PHP stack) is a bad idea.
- you don't need "remi" (php 5.4), only "remi-php56", except if you want some other packages from there, see http://blog.remirepo.net/post/2015/08/03/Remi-repository-is-changing

Comment: it was useful tnx dude !!